# JQuery Array for images

Tags: jquery, arrays, image

This is a silly little question, I know, but I can't seem to find the answer to it...

I'm trying to change an image in Jquery using an array with the names, but it reads n, g and 2 instead of the actual values.

My code is:

```
var huidig = 1;
var arrayTekenen = jQuery.makeArray("peng1.png","peng2.png","peng3.png","peng4.png");

$(document).ready(
     function() {
         $('#next').bind('click', ClickNext);
     }
 )
 function ClickNext() {
    if(huidig<4)
       {
        huidig++; 
       }

    $("#tekenstap").attr('src', 'img/' + arrayTekenen[huidig]); 
 }
```

This is the error I get when clicking the object:

> Failed to load resource (15:27:28:901 | error, network)   at
>   http:// localhost:8383/HTML5Application/img/n Failed to load resource
>   (15:27:30:048 | error, network)   at
>   http:// localhost:8383/HTML5Application/img/g Failed to load resource
>   (15:27:30:729 | error, network)   at
>   http:// localhost:8383/HTML5Application/img/2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, thanks, forgot that for a second there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery.makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) doesn't do what you think it does.

It's not there to create an array. It transforms an array-like to a real array, and takes only one argument: the array-like.

If you want to create an array, use the following syntax:

```
var arrayTekenen = ["peng1.png","peng2.png","peng3.png","peng4.png"];
```

Some resource you should read: [MDN Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Now you're asking me: what's an array-like object? It's an object that looks like an array, quacks like an array, walks like an array, but isn't an array. Examples are [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), [NodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) or [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Mainly, they can be used as arrays, but don't have the array methods like `slice`, `splice`, `forEach`, etc.

What `$.makeArray` does is basically this:

```
function makeArray(obj) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
}
```

I leave it to you to understand how this works :-)

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. The amount of help I get from the people on this website is amazing.

Comment: You're welcome! This kind of comment is what makes it worthwile to contribute on this website :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine +1, great answer and attitude.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine +1 You had me at quacks like an array. Great answer and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how [`jQuery.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) works.  Just use array literal notation:

```
var arrayTekenen = ["peng1.png","peng2.png","peng3.png","peng4.png"];
```

In your case, arrayTekenen turns out to be a string ("peng2.png") so arrayTekenen[i] is a character instead of the filename.